# How to get the attribute of an option

Tags: javascript, html

I have create a dynamic dropdown using JS

```
var str = `<select onchange="getPrice(this)"><option value="">Select</option>`;
for(var s=0;s<arr.length;s++) {
    str += `<option value="${arr[i].name}" price="${arr[i].price}">${arr[i].name}</option>`;
}
str += '</select>

function getPrice(ele) { 
    console.log(ele.value); //getting the value here
    console.log(ele.price); //getting null here 
}
```

`ele.price` is giving me null

Comment: use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) for price as js nodes don't have that attribute

Comment: `ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].getAttribute('price')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get the reference of `selected` option then use `getAttribute()`

```
ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].getAttribute('price')
```

However, I would recommend you to use `data-*` prefixed attribute

```
<option value="${arr[i].name}" data-price="${arr[i].price}">${arr[i].name}</option>
```

then `Element.dataset` property can be used.

```
var price = ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].dataset.price
```